# How can class implement interface with one property also implement other interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

Sorry for no clear title, It seems like common problem, but I can't find anything. I need to create class that implements interface like below, but why I get this error? Is there something missing, or it isn't possible to do things like that?

```
    public class Car : ICar
    {
        public Wheel Wheel { get; set; } //this makes relation in db
    }

    public interface ICar
    {
        IWheel Wheel { get; set; }
    }

    public class Wheel : IWheel
    {

    }

    public interface IWheel
    {

    }
```

Error:

```
'Car' does not implement interface member 'ICar.Wheel'. 'Car.Wheel' cannot implement 'ICar.Wheel' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IWheel'.
```

Comment: Your car needs to implement public IWheel Wheel { get; set; }, not public Wheel Wheel { get; set; }

Comment: `ICar` promises, that you can `set` _anything_ that implements `IWheel` as `Wheel`. But `Car` only accepts the specific implementation `Wheel` (and child classes of it), nothing else. So that's (one) problem.

Comment: Sorry @auburg, I edited post after you commented. I need to have Wheel Wheel, because it creates relation in db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the property from the interface *explicitly*:

```
public class Car : ICar
{
    public Wheel Wheel { get; set; }

    IWheel ICar.Wheel
    {
        get { return Wheel; }
        set { Wheel = (Wheel)value; }
    }
}
```

That way, users of your class will see the "original" `Wheel` property typed to the full-fledged `Wheel` class, whereas whoever uses the interface will get the explicit implementation (that, in your case, quite directly maps to the other property, but is, in any case, considered separate by the compiler).

Note the cast in the setter and its implications, in case the interface really needs to have a writeable property.

Comment: Looks kinda smelly i guess, but does the job for me and helps throw out bunch of repetitive code. Thanks!

Comment: @PiotrPiątkiewicz: I don't think there is anything smelly about having explicit interface implementations that internally call other class members. IMHO it helps to keep the public class interface clean and is a very legitimate use of explicit interface implementations.